# next_page_token error while using Places API in GoogleWay library in R

Tags: r, googleway

I am extracting nearby_places using Places API with Googleway Package in R.

Initially after providing the Key, I type in the Query and obtain the Values.

```
have_places <- google_places(location = c(1.4434068, 103.7769701),
                         radius = 500,
                         simplify = FALSE,
                         key = key)
```

After this, when I set the token, I get the following Error.

```
> token <- have_places$next_page_token
Error in have_places$next_page_token : 
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any suggestion's on what went wrong??

I did search the internet and when I type in the following command;

> token <- have_places[3]

I can obtain the next_page_token, but, with some junk values.

Comment: Have you been through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50495033/5977215 ?

Comment: Yes, been through that. I have a question on what does simplify does?

Comment: Does that link give you an answer to this question? And do you have a separate question on what `simplify` does?